# Does the relationship between continuity of a linear functional under two norms implies one norm is stronger than the other?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I am learning about the bounded inverse theorem on my own. One question analogous to the description of strong and weak norms is as follows:

Suppose $X$ is a vector space equipped with two norms $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$. If for any linear functional $f$ on $X$, that $f$ is continuous under $\|\cdot\|_1$ implies that $f$ is also continuous under $\|\cdot\|_2$. How can we prove that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that
$$
\|x\|_1\leqslant C\|x\|_2 \quad\forall x\in X.
$$
That is to say $\|\cdot\|_2$ is stronger than $\|\cdot\|_1$ on $X$.

I intuitively think the assumption implies there exists a constant $M>0$ such that $\|f\|_2\leqslant M\|f\|_1$, but fail to prove that.

Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @CyclotomicField Thanks for your attention. I think the assumption implies there exists a constant $M>0$ such that $||f||_2\leqslant M||f||_1$, which indirectly leads to the conclusion. Here the operator norm is induced respectively by norms in the assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $B$ be the unit ball of $X$ under the norm $||\cdot||_2$, $X^*_1$ be the continuous dual of $X$ under the norm $||\cdot||_1$. Then for each $f \in X^*_1$, since $f$ is also continuous under $||\cdot||_2$ by your assumption, we have $\sup_{x \in B} |f(x)| < \infty$. Regarding evaluation at $x \in B$ as a continuous map from $X^*_1$ to $\mathbb{C}$ allows us to apply the uniform boundedness principle. This yields that $\sup_{x \in B} ||\textrm{ev}_x||_{B(X^*_1, \mathbb{C})} \leq C$ for some constant $C > 0$. By Hahn-Banach, $||\textrm{ev}_x||_{B(X^*_1, \mathbb{C})} = ||x||_1$, so $\sup_{x \in B} ||x||_1 \leq C$. But this is exactly the same as saying $||x||_1 \leq C||x||_2$ for all $x \in X$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer that has extended my view.